# Escape template characters for RoR generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I'm trying to persuade the template that tags that use a template language are not meant to be commands but as plain text.

My output file should look like this (path: app/views/projects/index.js.erb):

```
<%# Render list for XHR requests %>
<%= smart_listing_update :projects %>
```

where the `:projects` is a variable

I have a template, which should generate this file(path: lib/templates/haml/scaffold/template.js.erb):

```
<%# Render list for XHR requests %>
<%= smart_listing_update :<%= plural_table_name %> %>
```

I have 2 problems with this template

1. `<%#` makes a comment, so the first line in output is invisible
2. `<%= smart_listing_update` looks for variable, but i need to display it as a text

Could anybody help me write `<%=` and `<%#` as it looks?

With current template I'll end up with an error

> /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/erb.rb:896:in
>   `eval': (erb):5: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting ')'
>   (SyntaxError) at(( smart_listing_update :<%= plural_table_name
>   ).to_s); @o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as I created question i found the answer.

the template should look like this

```
<%%# Render list for XHR requests %>
<%%= smart_listing_update :<%= plural_table_name %> %>
```

Notice double `%%` at the beggining of the tag,.